# reading multiple excel sheets and dropping the last row of each sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

My program reads in an Excel file that contains multiple sheets and concatenates them together. The issue is that the last row at the end of each sheet Totals and I don't want that row. Is there an argument that will drop the last row when I read the sheets in? And will I need to first read the sheets in and remove this last row before I run the concat function to avoid deleting out the wrong rows? I've tried using skipfooter = 0 and skipfooter = 1 but this threw an error message.

Comment: Does this strictly need to be in Pandas? I can think of a way to do it in OpenPYXL

Comment: That's a good question. I'm new-ish with Python but my program is using openpyxl also. It's using openpyxl, pandas, csv and xlrd

Answer (score 0):

I assume you using pandas to read xlsx where the excel file have multiple sheet with difference length of data and you want to drop the last row from each sheet, so you can use `[:-1]` like this :

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('report.xlsx',engine = 'openpyxl')
data = [df.parse(name)[:-1] for name in df.sheet_names]
```